# How to make it my code go back to a specific while loop in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to Python and I am trying to create a simple calculator. Sorry if my code is really messy and unreadable. I tried to get the calculator to do another calculation after the first calculation by trying to make the code jump back to while vi == true loop. I'm hoping it would then ask for the "Enter selection" again and then continue on with the next while loop. How do I do that or is there another way?

```
vi = True
ag = True
while vi == True:               #I want it to loop back to here
        op = input("Input selection: ")
        if op in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
            vi = False
while vi == False:
     x = float(input("insert first number: "))
     y = float(input("insert Second Number: "))
     break
#Here would be an If elif statement to carry out the calculation
while ag == True:
 again = input("Another calculation? ")
 if again in ("yes", "no"):
    ag = False
 else:
     print("Please input a 'yes' or a 'no'")
if again == "no":
    print("Done, Thank you for using Calculator!")
    exit()
elif again == "yes":
    print("okay!")
    vi = True   #I want this part to loop back
```

Comment: You could put it all inside another big while loop.

Comment: @khelwood alright, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nice start. To answer your question about whether there's another way to do what you're looking for; yes, there is generally more than one way to skin a cat.

Generally, I don't use `while vi==True:` in one section, then follow that up with `while vi==False:` in another since, if I'm not in `True` then `False` is implied. If I understand your question, then basically a solution is to nest your loops, or call one loop from within the other. Also, it seems to me like you're on the brink of discovering the `not` keyword as well as functions.

#### Code

```py
vi = True
while vi:
    print("MENU")
    print("1-Division")
    print("2-Multiplication")
    print("3-Subtraction")
    print("4-Addition")
    print("Any-Exit")
    op = input("Input Selection:")
    if op != "1":
        vi = False
    else:
        x = float(input("insert first number: "))
        y = float(input("insert Second Number: "))
        print("Placeholder operation")    
        ag = True
        while ag:
            again = input("Another calculation? ")
            if again not in ("yes", "no"):
                print("Please input a 'yes' or a 'no'")
            if again == "no":
                print("Done, Thank you for using Calculator!")
                ag = False
                vi = False
            elif again == "yes":
                print("okay!")
                ag = False
```

Of course, that's a lot of code to read/follow in one chunk. Here's another version that introduces functions to abstract some of the details into smaller chunks.

```py
def calculator():
    vi = True
    while vi:
        op = mainMenu()
        if op == "\n" or op == " ":
            return None
        x, y = getInputs()
        print(x + op + y + " = " + str(eval(x + op + y)))
        vi = toContinue()
    return None

def mainMenu():
    toSelect=True
    while toSelect:
        print()
        print("\tMENU")
        print("\t/ = Division; * = Multiplication;")
        print("\t- = Subtract; + = Addition;")
        print("\t**= Power")
        print("\tSpace or Enter to Exit")
        print()
        option = input("Select from MENU: ")
        if option in "/+-%** \n":
            toSelect = False
    return option

def getInputs():
    inpt = True
    while inpt:
        x = input("insert first number: ")
        y = input("insert second number: ")
        try:
            tmp1 = float(x)
            tmp2 = float(y)
            if type(tmp1) == float and type(tmp2) == float:
                inpt = False
        except:
            print("Both inputs need to be numbers. Try again.")
    return x, y

def toContinue():
    ag = True
    while ag:
        again = input("Another calculation?: ").lower()
        if again not in ("yes","no"):
            print("Please input a 'yes' or a 'no'.")
        if again == "yes":
            print("Okay!")
            return True
        elif again == "no":
            print("Done, Thank you for using Calculator!")
            return False
```